# fiddler web debugging tool TCPIP Connection time value Meaning

Tags: web, fiddler

To measure the performance of my Web application I used Fiddler tool
In one of my request analysis thru fiddler I found in statistics tab of fiddler 
there is a TCP/IP Connection , and that time is high round 21098 MS 
so I want to know what time does this entry represents.
connection time to the server from client ot the database time from server to the database server.

What is the TCP/IP connection time in the fiddler

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP Connection Time represents the time required to establish a TCP/IP connection. 21 seconds is very high, and is a "magic value" in TCP. A time of 21 seconds suggests that Fiddler was not able to make a connection to the server, and it took Windows 21 seconds to determine that the target server was not reachable.